# how to update a windows form GUI from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

how do you update a win forms control (ex. label, progress bar) from another class which created the GUI but not in the creating thread? (for example, an event handler of Program.cs)

I've found several posts regarding updating GUI from another thread using Invoke() method, but what i've found so far only works if the codes are written in the same class as the form

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the `Invoke` method on the form. For example:

```
private void someMethod() {
    myOtherForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
        // update things in myOtherForm here
    }));
}
```

If you don't need the updates to be finished before returning back to the method, you should use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.

Comment: @Amir: What the rest of the code looks like would depend on how your application is structured. Essentially, you need to have a reference to the other control you want to perform some operation on, and when you want to perform the operation, do the operation within the delegate passed to `Invoke`. Exactly how you'll do that depends on the structure of the application you're writing, so I can't give you any further guidance.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are two separate issues here:

- Updating the UI from a different class
- Updating the UI from a different thread

The two are almost completely orthogonal. Once you've solved each of them in isolation, you can put the two together.

If there are well-understood ways in which the UI needs to be changed (e.g. updating the text in a status bar or something like that) I would write methods in the UI class itself to do that, and just call those methods from the other class. Alternatively, you *can* expose the individual control of the UI - preferably through properties - and then use `Control.Invoke` in the normal way from the other class, e.g.

```
MethodInvoker action = () => form.StatusLabel.Text = "Finished";
form.BeginInvoke(action);
```

So long as you call `Invoke` on a control which "lives" on the same thread as all the controls you touch, it doesn't matter which one you use... so an alternative could be:

```
Label label = form.StatusLabel;
MethodInvoker action = () => label.Text = "Finished";
label.BeginInvoke(action);
```

One difference here is that in this latter code, the `StatusLabel` property is being evaluated in the worker thread - which *could* lead to race conditions if your UI is changing it to refer to different labels at different times. I would generally prefer the first approach.

(I agree with icktoofay's comment about `BeginInvoke` being preferable unless you really need to wait, by the way... although you do then need to be careful about changes to any variables captured by anonymous functions.)

Comment: @Amir: I can't really give any help without more details about *exactly* what you don't understand.

Comment: I don't know: How do i use `MethodInvoker` and `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: @Amir: Well I've *shown* you how you use them. I've given sample code.

Comment: How can i expose control of the UI and then use `Control.Invoke` form other class?

Comment: @Amir: It sounds like you should be asking a new and *detailed* question, rather than trying to do it all in comments with me having to guess at the context.

Comment: @JonSkeet so for my code I have: Form1.label14.Text = "whaterver" but I cant acces label14; what must I do?