# Update UI control by FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, treeview, filesystemwatcher

Im having some problems in my code:

```
private void start_watcher()
    {
        fswFiler = new FileSystemWatcher(Control.filer.get_path(),"*.*");

        //fswStorage = new FileSystemWatcher(Control.storage.get_path());

        fswFiler.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(updatePend);
        fswFiler.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(updatePend);
        fswFiler.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(updatePend);
        fswFiler.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(updatePend);

        fswFiler.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    private void updatePend(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.viewPend.Nodes.Clear();
        Control.filer.refresh_files_list();
        this.viewPend.Nodes.Add(Control.filer.get_files_node());
    }
```

throws me out of the program.
any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: Where or what line does it "Throw you out of the program"

Comment: `Control.filer.get_path()` what is this?

Comment: it doesnt throw an exception..

Comment: Control.filer.get_path() - returns a string of the directory path

Comment: @nadav you can find the line where it throws you out of the program by putting a breakpoint on the first line in updatePend and then go step by step in the code. Or you can enable Exceptions in Debug => Exceptions... => Mark the checkbox next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileSystemWatcher` notifications occur in another thread than the UI uses. You must `Invoke`
See:  [how to update a windows form GUI from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226293/how-to-update-a-windows-form-gui-from-another-class)

Or even better: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1)